# Memcached cross client compatability issue between telnet and Java (com.danga)

Tags: java, windows, memcached, couchbase

I am new to memcached and getting to know an old friend, Java -  am running on win x64 with java 1.7.  Also running the couchbase memcache server on my local win 64 machine via a setup file couchbase-server-enterprise_2.2.0_x86_64.  Everything generally works fine until I noticed a strange behavior when doing string comparisons with a key set in the telnet session and checking this key in java.

From the telnet session

```
set s1 1 0 4
abcd
STORED
set s2 32 0 4
abcd
STORED
```

From my main java test class:
    ...

```
System.out.println("Get s1 from Cache:" +mcca.get("s1"));
System.out.println("Get s1 from Cache:" +mcca.get("s1",1));
System.out.println("Get s1 from Cache:" +mcca.get("s1",32));
System.out.println("Get s1 from Cache:" +mcca.get("s1",77, true));

System.out.println("Get s2 a from Cache:" +mcca.get("s2"));
System.out.println("Get s2 b from Cache:" +mcca.get("s2",1));          
System.out.println("Get s2 c from Cache:" +mcca.get("s2",32));
System.out.println("Get s2 c from Cache:" +mcca.get("s2",77, true));
```

Outputs

```
Get s1 from Cache:97
Get s1 from Cache:97
Get s1 from Cache:97
com.danga.MemCached.MemCachedClient Mon Dec 30 11:50:06 EST 2013 - ++++ retrieving object and stuffing into a string.
Get s1 from Cache:abcd
Get s2 a from Cache:abcd
Get s2 b from Cache:abcd
Get s2 c from Cache:abcd
com.danga.MemCached.MemCachedClient Mon Dec 30 11:50:06 EST 2013 - ++++ retrieving object and stuffing into a string.
Get s2 c from Cache:abcd
```

I was looking here: http://www.geelou.com/javadocs/java_memcached-release_2.0.1/com/danga/MemCached/MemCachedClient.html  but I didn't see any explanation about the hashCode and whether it corresponds to the same flag/metadata parameter in the memcached server.

I think my question roughly boils down to:  can the com.danga get command hashCode parameter value be changed from 32 so that I can get the full string when I set the s1 key with metadata/flag 1 as shown above without having to specify the asString flag or mcca.setPrimitiveAsString(true)?

And related, why does

```
System.out.println("Get s2 a from Cache:" +mcca.get("s2"));
```

print what seems to be the correct value of abcd whereas neither of:

```
System.out.println("Get s1 from Cache:" +mcca.get("s1"));
System.out.println("Get s1 from Cache:" +mcca.get("s1",1));
```

print what seems to be the correct value of abcd?

As stated in this answer [Memcached getting null for String set with python and then get from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209864/memcached-getting-null-for-string-set-with-python-and-then-get-from-java) I can work around my issue using

```
mcca.setPrimitiveAsString(true);
mcca.setSanitizeKeys(false);
pool.setHashingAlg(SockIOPool.NEW_COMPAT_HASH);
```

but still I do not understand why the difference appears, and if/how I can modify the call to get parameters to fix it

Notes:
The reason for setting the flag/metadata parameter to 32 is that in another little java test I ran

```
System.out.println("set 1 status:" + mcc.set("1", "Modified"));

//which outputs
com.danga.MemCached.MemCachedClient Fri Dec 27 00:12:51 EST 2013 - ++++ memcache cmd (result code): set 1 32 0 8
(STORED)
```

This seems to indicate that the com.danga library is using a flag/metadata value of 32.

I think my question boils down to  ***From memcache telnet session***

```
set s1 1 0 4 
abcd  
set s2 32 0 4 
abcd
```

***From java***  Why does

```
mcca.get("s1")// only gives the first ascii character code (97) 
mcca.get("s2")// but gives the entire string.  What is so special about the second memcache command using the hash of 32?
```

Comment: As I understand you're trying to write into couchbase(or memcache) form client written in one language and get value by other client?

Comment: Yes, but with a specific scenario.  at the memcached telnet prompt if I enter: set s1 1 0 4
abcd     Then these two System.out.println("Get s1 from Cache:" +mcca.get("s1",1)); do not print the correct values, they only print 97 (ascii a).  This works: System.out.println("Get s1 from Cache:" +mcca.get("s1",77, true));  It seems the second parameter (either 1 or 77) does not matter, so how in Java com.danga does the second parameter work.  I thought if it matches what I do in the memcached telnet set then I should be able to read the entire parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your "flag" parameter is telling your library that the data is stored differently. I'm not sure why you're specifying "1" and "32" in the telnet SET commands, but you might want to test it with a different flag value specified.

The "1" and "32" you're specifying are often used by client libraries to specify the format the data is in. They are not hash values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Could you please clarify.  I think my question boils down to  ***From memcache telnet session*** set s1 1 0 4 abcd  set s2 32 0 4 abcd  *** From java***  why does mcca.get("s1") only give the first ascii code (97) but mcca.get("s2") gives the entire string.  What is so special about the second memcache command using the hash of 32?

Comment: The 32 is not a hash, it's a flag that client libraries can use to treat the data differently. I didn't look at the source, but I suspect that what is happening is that the flag is saying "this is a single byte" or "this data is compressed" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mixed the parameters.

Telnet:

```
set key metaData expiryTime lengthInBytes
set s1     1        0             4
```

Java:

https://github.com/gwhalin/Memcached-Java-Client

```
mc.get(key, hash); // <- retrieves key by hash
mc.keyExists(key);
mc.get(key, null, true);
```

https://github.com/gwhalin/Memcached-Java-Client/blob/master/src/com/meetup/memcached/MemcachedClient.java#L1237

Comment: Thanks for the source code link.  That is helfpul.  Please see my above comment.  I have added a section to my question at the bottom which has a summary of my issue.