# Doesn't Django cache support Integers?

Tags: php, python, django, caching

I am using PHP to populate my memcached, and Django to read the cache.

I have made my custom `make_key` function in Django `settings.py` so that the key is same and Django doesn't modify it.

```
def make_key(key, key_prefix, version):
    return key


CACHE_HOST = "localhost"

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': CACHE_HOST + ':11211',
        'KEY_FUNCTION': make_key
    }
}
```

Everything works fine while storing and retrieving strings to and from the cache. The issue came when I tried to store an integer value in memcache via. PHP using the following test snippet.

```
$host = "localhost";
$port = "11211";

$memObj = new Memcached();
$memObj->addServer($host, $port);
$memObj->set('sample_key', 123);
```

If I query the above key directly from the cache using `telnet localhost 11211`, I am able to see the value. But, when I do it from Django, I get `None`. Following is my Django test snippet.

```
from django.core.cache import cache

print(cache.get('sample_key')) # prints None
```

Now, if I set the key in Django, then I am able to get it as well in Django.

```
cache.set('sample_key', 123)
print(cache.get('sample_key')) # prints 123
```

Till this point, it was concluded that I can **set** the cache as integer **in Django** and **get** it in **Django**, **PHP** and **Telnet**, but, if I set the cache as integer **in PHP**, I can only **get** it in **PHP** and **Telnet**.

```
+--------+---------------------+
| SET    | GET                 |
+--------+---------------------+
| Django | Django, PHP, Telnet |
+--------+---------------------+
| PHP    | PHP, Telnet         |
+--------+---------------------+
```

After a few debugging, I discovered that when when Django sets an `Integer`, it actually sets it as a `Double`. I found this from php `var_dump`.

```
var_dump($memObj->get('sample_key')); # prints double(123)
```

Now, I tried setting the integer as a double in PHP. And surprisingly Django is able to get it.

```
$memObj->set('sample_key', 123.0);
```

in Django,

```
print(cache.get('sample_key')) # prints 123
```

**tl;dr;**

```
$memObj->set('sample_key', 123.0); # in PHP
print(cache.get('sample_key')) # in Django # prints 123

$memObj->set('sample_key', 123); # in PHP
print(cache.get('sample_key')) # in Django # prints None
```

**So, what is the issue here, how do I SET an integer in PHP and GET it in Django?**

Answer (score 0):

This is highly related to [Memcached getting null for String set with python and then get from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209864/memcached-getting-null-for-string-set-with-python-and-then-get-from-java)

You need to configure your python library dealing with memcache to enhance compatibility between languages